# Layout issue with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, line-breaking

On the screenshot you can see that the ISBN number breaks the layout:

[image: broken layout]

How can I fix the layout?

On my small attatched example the layout is not so much demaged like in my real work but you will see also the problem.

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    12pt,
    bibtotoc,
    liststotoc,
    ]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, natbib=true, citestyle=alphabetic, bibstyle=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\bibliography{source}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Intro}
Some info \cite{Hoehne2010}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And my bibtex file:

```
@BOOK{Hoehne2010,
  title = {Verfahren zur Anonymisierung von Einzeldaten},
  publisher = {Statistisches Bundesamt},
  year = {2010},
  author = {Höhne, Jörg},
  series = {Statistik und Wissenschaft, Teil 16},
  address = {Wiesbaden},
  isbn = {9783824609017},
  type = {text},
  url = {http://www.destatis.de}
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Long strings in bibliographies often give problems in line breaking. A "cheap" solution in this case is to use the hyphened form of the ISBN number:

```
978-3-8246-0901-7
```

This is the "official" style: the first group corresponds to "book publishing", the second is the language (3 is German); then come the publisher and the title; the last one is the check digit.

See [here](http://www.destatis.de/jetspeed/portal/cms/Sites/destatis/Internet/DE/Content/Publikationen/StatistikundWissenschaft/Band16__AnonymisierungEinzeldaten,templateId=renderPrint.psml) for a reference for this particular book. You can also check at the [ISBN organization converter](http://www.isbn-international.org/ia/isbncvt)

Note: rekire has pointed me to another online resource:

http://toolserver.org/isbn/IsbnCheckAndFormat

that is also able to check with some databases for the corresponding book.