# Reduce font size of bibliography; overfull bibliography

Tags: biblatex, fontsize

I am using Biber (backend of `biblatex`) to  make the bibliography. I have two questions about the bibliography.

1. I want to use a reduced font ONLY for the bibliography (not the citation in the text, that in my text is in numeric style e.g. [1], [2] etc.). In particular, the font of my text is 11 pt and I want to print the bibliography in 10 pt.
2. In the bibliography some text exceeds the text cage, because the ISBN is printed without a break. What is the command I should use for avoid this overfull `hbox`?

Comment: Ad 1: [How to change font size for bibliography?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1441/35864) or [Biblatex: Changing the font of citation-marks and the references?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6953/35864)

Comment: Ad 2: [Layout issue with biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39521/35864) and [Handling overflows in biblatex bibliographies](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50957/35864). If that does not help we will probably need to know a bit more about your problem.

Comment: Shameless promotions for one of my answers: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/442308/35864 tries to discuss some of the most common overfull/underfull box/line breaking problems in `biblatex`-generated bibliographies and possible solutions.

Answer (score 48):

I found this command:

```
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\small}
```

and work well. (first question).

For the second question, for now I used to break the ISBN with line (XXX-X-XXXX-XXXX-X, standard 13-number ISBN code). But I'm searching for a more general rule to avoid overfull in bibliography (for example, when I tried to use small font, a DOI URL exceeded the cage text; in this case a manual break doesn't work, because the URL doesn't work after text break)

Comment: There are several ways to facilitate proper line breaking in URLs [Line breaks of long URLs in bibliography?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134191/35864) or similar questions. To avoid overfull boxes one should make sure that there are enough places where a break can be inserted (make sure the right hyphenation patterns are loaded, have a look at URL line breaks [etc.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44523/35864)). Of course one can always go for a [ragged right](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41154/35864) bibliography.

Comment: If you use the right set-up, URLs do break (at certain sensible places by default, and after some modification (`biburlnumpenalty`, `biburlucpenalty`, `biburllcpenalty`, [see here - you *do not* have to copy all the code, you only need the `\setcounter` part at the end, I mainly linked to this post for an explanation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22871/35864) and the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) §4.10.3 *User-definable Lengths and Counters*, p. 222) even at not-so-very-sensible ones)

Comment: Daniele, could you add an example on how to use your command? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

For the first question, in the bibliography section you can change the main font size, just as you do it in some particular section.

For example:

```
\bibliographystyle{Users/Daniele/Thesis/plainnat.bst}
%
{\small \bibliography{Users/Daniele/Thesis/bibliography}}
```

There are plenty font sizes: `\tiny`, `\scriptsize`, `\footnotesize`, `\small`, `\normalsize`, `\large`, `\Large`, `\LARGE`, `\huge` and `\Huge`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Notice please that this answer doesn't answer the OPs problem. He uses biblatex, your solution works for BibTeX. As well, I need to remark that using absolute pathes of any kind is very frowned upon.

Comment: This will not work. `biblatex` does not use the `\bibliographystyle` command and `\bibliography` is not used in the same way.

Comment: Thanks for this answer as it's for bibtex which I'm using. the `{\small ...}` technique did the trick to reduce the font size of my bibliography.

Comment: `\tiny` in my case worked well, and I'm using `beamer`

Answer (score 4):

Here is an option for people who use `biblatex`, add

```latex
\AtBeginBibliography{\small}
```

in the preamble **after** you import `biblatex`.

---

By the way, in Daniele's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/203783/85946), please note that you also have to put `\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\small}` after you import `biblatex`.

Comment: `\bibfont` is defined by `biblatex` as well (the default definition from `biblatex.def` is `\newcommand*{\bibfont}{\normalfont\normalsize}`) and Daniele's answer works perfectly well with `biblatex`. (Though having seen the original definition one might be inclined to say `\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\normalfont\small}` instead.) Of course `\AtBeginBibliography` still works fine as well, but `\bibfont` just feels a little bit "more right" for font changes.

Comment: @moewe I put `\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\scriptsize}` before `\usepackage{biblatex}`, which caused the conflict I described. So I will update my answer accordingly. Thanks!