# Bib(la)tex error when compiling beamerposter template

Tags: biblatex, biber, beamerposter

Dears

I have downloaded this template http://www.latextemplates.com/template/jacobs-landscape-poster but when compiling it, the `texmaker` gives me the following error:

```
Process started

INFO - This is Biber 2.5 INFO - Logfile is 'main.blg'

ERROR - Cannot find control file 'main.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX? INFO - ERRORS: 1

Process exited with error(s)
```

Now I have recently updated my `texmaker` preferences to use biber instead of bibtex (based on suggestions I read here) by entering `"/usr/texbin/biber" %`

How to overcome this error? the bibliography in the template is mentioned as follows

```
\nocite{*} % Insert publications even if they are not cited in the poster
\small{\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{sample}\vspace{0.75in}}
```

Thank You

Comment: The template doe not use the modern system of `biblatex` and `biber`. You would have to do the transformation yourself.

Comment: unrelated to the biber question  but `\small` does not take an argument so `\small{...}` should be `{\small...}`

Comment: You can't use biber with this template but should use bibtex (or as suggested by Johannes change the template to use biblatex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, the issue is I need to either stick with bibtex or alter the template accordingly to make it working with biblatex. I chose the later and based on the answers in [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex) I succeeded in doing so.

Simply, remove

```
\nocite{*} % Insert publications even if they are not cited in the poster
\small{\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{sample}\vspace{0.75in}}
```

and add

```
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}
```

to your preamble and `\printbibliography` to the reference block

```
\begin{block}{References}
\printbibliography
\end{block}
```

Lastly, to have references with *small* font size see [this Answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/203783/21858)