# Correcting format of references

Tags: biblatex

I need my references to look more pro. At the moment, my references look like this;[image: My_references].

I want them to look more like this without the blue color;
[image: HH_references]

That means removal of the parenthesis and making them appear more compact. I am using the following style `\usepackage[backend=bibtex,natbib=true,style=chem-acs]{biblatex}`. Here is my preamble;

```
\documentclass[12pt,danish,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[journal=rsc]{chemstyle}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,natbib=true,style=chem-acs]{biblatex}
\bibliography{ref} 
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\parskip=0.1in
\begin{document}
Bla bla bla\supercite{Step_1} bla bla bla\supercite{Step_2}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Here is my ref file;

```
    @article{Step_1,
author = {Yamamoto, Kosuke and Bruun, Theodora and Kim, Jung Yun and Zhang, Lei and Lautens, Mark},
title = {A New Multicomponent Multicatalyst Reaction (MC)2R: Chemoselective Cycloaddition and Latent Catalyst Activation for the Synthesis of Fully Substituted 1,2,3-Triazoles},
journal = {Org. Lett.},
volume = {\textsl{18}},
number = {11},
pages = {2644-2647},
year = {2016},
doi = {10.1021/acs.orglett.6b00975},
URL = { 
        http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/acs.orglett.6b00975

},
eprint = { 
        http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/acs.orglett.6b00975

}

}
%%
%%
@article{Step_2,
  doi = {10.1055/s-1995-3905},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1055/s-1995-3905},
  year  = {1995},
  month = {mar},
  publisher = {Thieme Publishing Group},
  volume = {\textsl{1995}},
  number = {03},
  pages = {290},
  author = {Alicia Torrado and Susana L{\'{o}}pez and Rosana Alvarez and Angel R. de Lera},
  title = {General Synthesis of Retinoids and Arotinoids via Palladium-Catalyzed Cross-Coupling of Boronic Acids with Electrophiles},
  journal = {Synthesis}
}
```

Comment: Where is that setting supposed to go in my preamble?

Comment: For reducing the font size, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203764/reduce-font-size-of-bibliography-overfull-bibliography and linked questions.

Comment: Do you want your bibliography to be two-columns wide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the numbers by changing the option `biblabel` to `dot`.
If you want the references to appear more "compact" you have to adjust the font size by setting `\bibfont` to `\small`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,danish,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[journal=rsc]{chemstyle}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib=true,style=chem-acs,biblabel=dot]{biblatex} % <-- Here
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\small} % <-- Set font size to small

\addbibresource{ref.bib}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\parskip=0.1in
\begin{document}
Bla bla bla\supercite{Step_1} bla bla bla\supercite{Step_2}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or even smaller:

```
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\footnotesize}
```

[image]